# JQuery поменять элементы местами

Tags: html, jquery

Как можно менять местами блоки? Чтобы каждые 10 секунд последний блок вставал на место первого, второй на место третьего, третий на место последнего. И так по кругу.

```
<div data-id='0'>0</div>
<div data-id='1'>1</div>
<div data-id='2'>2</div>
<div data-id='3'>3</div>
```

Comment: банально брать последний блок - удалять его, занося в переменную и вставлять перед первым. всё. поставив это на `setInterval`

Comment: О, точно, спасибо!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

При перемещении блока не надо удалять из старого места, при вставке в новое он будет удален из старого автоматически.
Сделал без jQuery на чистом JS.

```js
var parent = document.getElementById('container');
setInterval(function() {
  var div = parent.querySelector('div');
  parent.appendChild(div); //автоматически удалится из старого места
}, 1000);
```

```css
#container div 
{
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 20px;
  border: 2px solid silver;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div data-id='0'>0</div>
  <div data-id='1'>1</div>
  <div data-id='2'>2</div>
  <div data-id='3'>3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: только нужно в обратную сторону.....

Answer (score 1):

Решил данным способом:

```
setInterval(function() {
    $('.cen p').hide();
    $('.cen').prepend($('.cen p:last'));
    $('.cen p').slideToggle({duration: "slow",});
}, 5000);
```

Comment: для красоты slideToggle добавил) можно ещё какой-нибудь fadeIn или Out